# How can i activate tab in angularjs with foundations tab

Tags: javascript, angularjs, zurb-foundation

I am using Angular js with foundations

http://pineconellc.github.io/angular-foundation/

Now i have two tabs on the page which work fine like this

```
<tabset>
            <tab heading="tab1"> </tab>
            <tab heading="tab2"> </tab>
</tabset>
```

My problem is that i have the variable called  `$scope.isdata`

i want that if that variable is `true` then `tab1` should be active  and if false then `tab2` should be active.

But i also want that if some manually clicks on either tabs then corrosonding tab should be visible

EDIT: I get this error

```
TypeError: undefined is not a function
    at Object.<anonymous> (/bower_components/angular-foundation/mm-foundation-tpls.min.js:8:23667)
    at Object.applyFunction [as fn] (<anonymous>:778:50)
    at Scope.$digest (/bower_components/angular/angular.js:12031:29)
    at Scope.$delegate.__proto__.$digest (<anonymous>:844:31)
    at Scope.$apply (/bower_components/angular/angular.js:12279:24)
    at Scope.$delegate.__proto__.$apply (<anonymous>:855:30)
    at done (/bower_components/angular/angular.js:7991:45)
    at completeRequest (/bower_components/angular/angular.js:8196:7)
    at XMLHttpRequest.xhr.onreadystatechange (bower_components/angular/angular.js:8137:11)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
<tab heading="tab1" active='isdata'> </tab>
<tab heading="tab2" active='!isdata'> </tab>
```

Comment: I tried that but when i click on tabs then i get some `dbg undefined error in firebug console` . becuse may be when i click the foundation also try to update the active table which already has our value but i am not sure